# make iOS text to speech work when ringer is muted

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I am calling iOS text to speech in a pretty standard way:

```
static AVSpeechSynthesizer* synthesizer = NULL;
//...
+(void)readText:(NSString*)text
{
    if(synthesizer == NULL)
    synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"fr-FR"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

It does the job, except for one issue: when the ringer is muted on device, text to speech is muted too. How do I make it work even when the ringer is muted?

Comment: I'm assuming that's exactly what the ringer is made for. So no developer like you can bypass the muted state and play sounds while the user expects the phone to be quiet.

Comment: Previously I assumed that the ringer is just for muting phone calls and messages. Now it is clear that it's more complex than that: [http://artoftheiphone.com/2012/02/10/basics-what-does-the-iphone-ringer-switch-mute-and-not-mute/]. Still, many apps do make sound with ringer off (e.g. a browser playing YouTube), and I'd like to bypass it, because that seems the expected behavior in my case.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth nope, you can active the audio even if the device is muted.

Answer (score 3):

iOS audio session categories are the correct answer for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html.

The default value is `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`, but if the audio functionality is central for the app (our case), it should be set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just unmute the device

```
static AVSpeechSynthesizer* synthesizer = NULL;
//...
+(void)readText:(NSString*)text
{
    if(synthesizer == NULL)
    synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"fr-FR"];

    //Add the following code to active audio
    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    //magic is here
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr]; 

    //speech your text
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Comment: Will Apple approve this, though? As mentioned in section 2.5.9 of [Apple’s app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements), apps may not alter the function of standard switches. Changing the current ringing state, might be considered a violation of this guideline.

Comment: 1) how do you know? 2) Facebook is never a good reference, and neither should be Twitter. These apps do have special permissions; they’re even natively integrated into the OS!

Comment: Leo, there is no need to force unmute. Setting the correct audio category (AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback) is enough. So the 'magic' line is unneccessary. See my answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Leo Cavalcante. After setting AVAudioSession setCategory and others, it solves my problem.

I have added swift code below.

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
       // try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```